# Iterate hash in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I iterate through this and get to use the values in the structs?

```
"[{\"username\":\"aw\"},{\"username\":\"api\"},{\"companyname\":\"dd\",\"username\":\"dd\"},{\"companyName\":\"Testing\"}]"
```

I want to get just the `username`, this is a product of call on a database designed with mongodb.

Comment: @Samuele This edit changes the nature of the question. It was a string and you make a js object...

Comment: it didn't feel like a string at all, more like a messed up code pasted here. that's why i edited in the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you must convert it to JavaScript array. In jQuery you can do it using method [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/). So code will be looks like this:

```
var results = $.parseJSON(resultsFromMongoDB);
for (var i in results) {
    if (results[i]['username'] != undefined) {
        var username = results[i]['username']
        // Some code...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
arr = JSON.Parse(yourString).map(function(item){
     return item.username;
});
```

Comment: Edited : [the item is the first argument given to the callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 0):

This is JSON.

You need to parse it in order to have a javascript object.

You can then iterate on the array :

```
var obj = JSON.parse("[{\"username\":\"aw\"},{\"username\":\"api\"},{\"companyname\":\"dd\",\"username\":\"dd\"},{\"companyName\":\"Testing\"}]");

for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
{
    console.log(obj[i].username);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**edit**] question changed:

<strike>No need for JSON here, it's an array</strike> you can parse it and use the `filter` and/or `map` method:

```
var usernames = JSON.parse(yourResultStringFromMongoDb)
   .filter(function(a){return a.username;})
   .map(function(a){return a.username});
//=> ["aw", "api", "dd"]
```

[**See also ...**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: @Kooilinc OP didn't change the question. Samuele changed it in an edit because he  thought the string was just a messed formatting (no way to know if he was right).